# Insert browsed image using wpf

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I need to insert an image to MySql using WPF.
The image can be selected value of browse&choose button.
Only I don't have enough experience with browse&choose image insertion.
byte[] ImageBytes = (byte[])PredictedHelpNeededArea; 
Below is my code:

`<Button x:Name="btnBrowse" Content="Browse" Click="btnBrowse_Click"/>
<Button x:Name="btnInsert" Content="Insert" Click="btnInsert_Click"/>
<Image Name="MyImage"></Image>`

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        {                
            if (MyImage.Source != null)
            {
                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO images (Image_BLOB) VALUES (@ImageSource)", con);
                byte[] ImageBytes = (byte[])PredictedHelpNeededArea;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ImageSource", MySqlDbType.Blob, ImageBytes.Length).Value = ImageBytes;
                con.Open();
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Image Inserted");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Choose an image");
            }
        }

    }

    private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Stream checkStream = null;
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Multiselect = false;
        openFileDialog.Filter = "All Image Files | *.*";
        if ((bool)openFileDialog.ShowDialog())
        {
            try
            {
                if ((checkStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(openFileDialog.FileName, UriKind.Absolute));                       
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully done");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }

        }
        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Problem occured, try again later");

        }
    }
```

Comment: *'I don't have enough experience'* isn't really much of a problem statement.  What is your *specific* issue?